# Deploy Azure Web Application locally

Tags: asp.net, localhost, web-deployment

I cloned a tfvc repository that basically is a web application.
I am trying to deploy it locally so I can continue to develop the application but it doesn't start up, I have followed these steps:

1- In IIS Added the Application, pointing the physical path to the folder with the solution ..\src\Something.Web

2- In Visual Studio right click on Something.Web -> Publish -> Web Server (IIS) -> Web Deploy Package -> (Select Path where I zipped the solution) ->C:\PRJ\Something.Web.zip
Site Name: Something.Web

3- Right click solution Something.Web -> Properties -> Web -> Project Url (http://localhost/Something.Web)  with Local IIS

4- Run (IIS Express Google Chrome)

403 Fobidden on Chrome
And a visual studio error with:
The remote server returned an error:(404) Not found
Click Help for more information

Since the Help button isn't helping much I decided to create this post. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing IIS Express with IIS. Pick one or the other. If you're using IIS, you shouldn't configure it to look at the folder your solution is in, rather you should point it to the folder you published your app to.